# Including a locally developed python package in a buildout interpreter

Tags: python, buildout

I'm using isotoma.buildout.autodevelop to develop eggs which I'm currently developing within my buildout.

I would like to include these developed eggs (which are located on the filesystem next to my buildout.cfg) as namespaces in my buildout's custom interpreter.

Can anyone provide an example of this or link to some resource ?

Comment: Can you expand your question a little? What is your custom interpreter? What do you expect to work, and how doesn't it work? I don't know what you mean with "namespaces in my buildout's custom interpreter", for example.

Answer (score 1):

In buildout you can use the develop option:

```
[buildout]
develop = .
  ../package_name
  ../another_package_name
```

In this example the current directory and two other packages in the parent directory will be included during the buildout process.

Answer (score 0):

A) The mr.developer recipe mentioned on your recipe's page is probably a better choice.

B) you want your eggs in bin/python? Include them in 'eggs' in your zc.recipe.eggs part in your buildout where you generate bin/python.